# How to convert Ajax to Fetch API in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fetch-api, rivescript

So I am using the [JavaScript port of RiveScript](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rivescript/1.17.2/rivescript.js) which uses ajax and of course I don't want to use jQuery anymore. There is only one line ajax and I want to change it to the new Fetch API.

```
**FYI: You can see the ajax code in line 1795 of the CDN.**
```

So here's the original code:

```
return $.ajax({
    url: file,
    dataType: "text",
    success: (function(_this) {
        return function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
            _this.say("Loading file " + file + " complete.");
            _this.parse(file, data, onError);
            delete _this._pending[loadCount][file];
            if (Object.keys(_this._pending[loadCount]).length === 0) {
                if (typeof onSuccess === "function") {
                    return onSuccess.call(void 0, loadCount);
                }
            }
        };
    })(this),
    error: (function(_this) {
        return function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            _this.say("Ajax error! " + textStatus + "; " + errorThrown);
            if (typeof onError === "function") {
                return onError.call(void 0, textStatus, loadCount);
            }
        };
    })(this)
});
```

and here's what I tried so far using the Fetch API:

```
return fetch(file, {
        dataType: "text"
    })
    .then(function(_this) {
        return function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
            _this.say("Loading file " + file + " complete.");
            _this.parse(file, data, onError);
            delete _this._pending[loadCount][file];
            if (Object.keys(_this._pending[loadCount]).length === 0) {
                if (typeof onSuccess === "function") {
                    return onSuccess.call(void 0, loadCount);
                }
            }
        };
    })
    .catch(function(_this) {
        return function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            _this.say("Ajax error! " + textStatus + "; " + errorThrown);
            if (typeof onError === "function") {
                return onError.call(void 0, textStatus, loadCount);
            }
        };
    })
```

The app code:

```
var bot = new RiveScript();

bot.loadFile("./brain.rive", loading_done, loading_error);


function loading_done (batch_num) {
    console.log("Batch #" + batch_num + " has finished loading!");

    bot.sortReplies();

    var reply = bot.reply("local-user", "Hello, bot!");
    console.log("The bot says: " + reply);
}

function loading_error (error) {
    console.log("Error when loading files: " + error);
}
```

Using the Fetch API, I'm not seeing any error now though I'm also not seeing any error or success messages.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: What is the purpose of returning a function from `.then()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [fetch init object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch#Parameters) doesn’t have a `dataType` key.

To indicate you want plain text back, add an `Accept: text/plain` header to the request:

```
fetch(file, {
    headers: {
      "Accept": "text/plain"
    },
  })
```

And the `fetch` call returns a promise that resolves with a [`Response` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response), and that `Response` object provides [methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response#Methods) that resolve with [text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text), [JSON data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json), or a [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/blob) — which means the basic form for handling the response from your `fetch(…)` call is like this:

```
fetch(file, {
  headers: {
    "Accept": "text/plain"
  },
})
.then(response => response.text())
.then(text => {
  // Do something with the text
})
```

So you need to take the existing code in the question and fit it into that form.

Comment: Thank you sir. I finally got the text, and now converting it properly as desired.